# how to get binary data or blob from javascript http request in java servlet , request payload in formdata

Tags: java, servlets, redis, blob, multipartform-data

how to get binary data or blob from JavaScript HTTP request in java servlet , request payload in formdata with paramters contains blob image, customerid, status etc. Here I need to get blob data in java servlet and save that blob data into redis server. 
Currently I am unable to parse blob data from the request.

Comment: where is your code ? try adding it.

Comment: just need to know how to handle binary data from request. I am trying to add code but some error is occuring.